# Python sqlite with opencv

Tags: python, sqlite, opencv

I am accessing my web camera by the help of opencv. So when I clicked the photo i want it to be store directly to database. I am able to store image file in local disk then uploading it to database. But i want to store it directly to database.

Comment: Please post your code . This will help us narrow down the issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way of storing directly to database by using image as BLOB datatype and converting the image into binary form with the help of sqlite3.Binary
The code i have written is in the figure:
[code for storing image directly to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkF42.png)